# Anime where in the first episode, the main character is new to a school that happens to have demons/monsters in it

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember watching the first episode of an anime, but I don't remember the name of it: it might have been made between 2014 and 2018. I can recall bits and pieces of it in hopes that someone may know what I am talking about.

There is a male student (the main character) who is new to a school that happens to have demons/monsters in it (it's not a school for monsters, but it happens to have monsters secretly within it). The monsters seem to hide in the shadows of the school. I'm not sure if the main character uses a device or not to see these monsters, but as the new student is being shown around the school he witnesses someone being feasted on in a classroom. I think the main character has a special sense for the monsters. He is also the only one who notices the feast.

Fast forward to the last part that I remember. The main character talks to what I'm assuming is an angel, outside on the roof, I believe. I also think there is a prominent female character who is like the secondary main character.

This is all I remember. Its not *High school of the elite* or *High school dxd* but similar in a sense of highschool.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made? Also, are there any similar anime which you can confirm aren't the right one?

Comment: To confirm, it's not a school for monsters, but it happens to have monsters secretly within it?

Comment: And the monsters aren't a series of scantily-clad girls who're incomprehensibly attracted to the main character?

Comment: Are the other students completely unaware of the monsters? Does anyone else notice the feast? Or perhaps they only see the student being attacked by something invisible?

Comment: @LogicDictates thanks, it might have been made between 2014 and 2018. Its not high school of the elite or high school dxd but similar in a sense of highschool.

Comment: @Showsni exactly right

Comment: @Valorum lol i think I know which one you mean and its not that one but thanks for that one

Comment: @qazmlpok I think the main character has a special sense for them. He is also the only one who notices the feast.

Comment: @J1O2S3H So more of a "My Monster Secret" situation than a "Rosario+Vampire" one. :)

Answer (score 3):

Could this be *['Angel Beats!'](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/AngelBeats)*?

> Our viewpoint character, high-school-aged Otonashi wakes up suddenly to find that he can't remember anything, not even his full name. Before he even has time to get his bearings, a purple-haired girl with a sniper rifle informs him that he is dead and asks him to join her rebellion against God... but God is nowhere to be seen.
>
> The world they are in seems like an enormous Japanese boarding school populated by soulless, though realistic and harmless, NPCs who act like ordinary students and faculty. The only apparent enemy of the self-named Shinda Sekai Sensen (Afterlife Battlefront) is the student council president, a short, white-haired girl they call Tenshi (Angel), who wields supernatural powers in an effort to force the SSS to behave like the normal students.

Comment: I don't recall *Angel Beats* having demons or monsters in it. The closest thing to an antagonist is Kanade/Tenshi, the angel-type character, and she certainly never "feasts on" anyone.

Comment: @F1Krazy - I was thinking about having a chat on the tropey school roof with an angel

Comment: @F1Krazy not quite but you def put me on to a new anime